# Errors in Drude model for thermal conductivity in metals

Tags: electrical-resistance, thermal-conductivity, metals

According to the Drude model the thermal conductivity comes out to be
$\kappa = \frac{1}{3}v^2\tau c_v$ the derivation of this is given in wikipedia also there it is mentioned about the errors made in the derivation as follows:-

> Drude made two assumptions now known to be errors. First, he used the classical result for the specific heat capacity of the conduction electrons: $c_v = \frac{3}{2}nk_B$. This overestimates the electronic contribution to the specific heat capacity by a factor of roughly 100. Second, Drude used the classical mean square velocity for electrons, $\frac{1}{2}mv^2 = \frac{3}{2}k_BT$. This underestimates the energy of the electrons by a factor of roughly 100. The cancellation of these two errors results in a good approximation to the conductivity of metals. In addition to these two estimates, Drude also made a statistical error and overestimated the mean time between collisions by a factor of 2. This confluence of errors gave a value for the Lorenz number that was remarkably close to experimental values.

I want to know the reason of first two errors about overestimation and underestimation. Also in the equation for $\kappa$ there is a root mean square velocity v why is it assumed constant? The reason for v being constant given in wikipedia is that v does not vary much with temperature, but then drude also assumed $\frac{1}{2}mv^2 = \frac{3}{2}k_BT$ which would have let him conclude that v varies proportionaly with square root of temperature.

Lastly,

> Drude also made a statistical error and overestimated the mean time between collisions by a factor of 2

But Drude just assumed the time to be $\tau$ what and where did he made a statistical error?

Comment: Could you post the link to the quoted Wikipedia article?

Comment: @RogerVadim https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drude_model

Comment: Essentially, he used classical description where one must use quantum one. Check this one: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_specific_heat

Comment: I am working on an answer, but for now just let me suggest a useful and famous book where these problems are discussed in detail: Aschcroft-Mermin, Solid State Physics :)